# How to take id as selector when used hash?

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose of the following html:

```
<div id='test#1'>test1</div>
<div id='test#2'>test2</div>
```

Now, the following wouldn't work, why?

css....

```
#test#1{color: red;}
```

jQuery....

```
$('#test#2').css('color','blue');
```

Comment: That's not a valid ID in your HTML. Remove the `#`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: how's that duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use any of the meta-characters such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~  as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with backslashes:

css way:

```
#test\#1{
    color: red;
}
```

jquery way:

```
$('#test\\#2').css('color','blue');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/252Y8/)

---

**Recommendation:**

You should not use # in your id [see more for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

---

So, you may be also wondering id="test.1" can be used and for this too you should escape the character as described above.

Comment: To be fair, what he *should* do is not use `#` in identifiers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `#` with backslash `\`:

```
#test\#1{
    color: red;
}
```

with jQuery, you can do the same way but you need to escape the `\` with another backslash:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
$('#test\\#2').css('color','blue');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vc2t4/)**

However, `#` is not a valid unique identifier according to [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

and [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) as well:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

So you should remove second `#` in your id.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use \ when using special characters

```
var test1 = $('#test\\#1');
```

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4944