# Jquery .clone() method does not work in IE and Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to clone a html control and then append to another control.

I have written code

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.multiFileUpload = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {


        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            controlId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.controlId);
        //primaryKey = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.primaryKey);

        var progressMonitorID = controlId + '-ProgressMonitor';
        var progressIndicatorID = controlId + '-ProgressIndicator';

        $(element).after('<div id=' + progressMonitorID + ' class="progress progress-striped active">'
                            + '<div id=' + progressIndicatorID + ' class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>'
                            //+ '<input type="hidden" id="imageKey_"' + controlId + '  name="imageKey" value=' + primaryKey + '></div>'
                       + '</div>');

        $('#' + progressMonitorID).hide();
        $('#' + progressIndicatorID).hide();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            imageKey = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.imageKey),
            imageForeighKey01 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.imageForeighKey01),
            uploadUrl = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.uploadUrl),
            controlId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.controlId),
            refreshUri = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.refresh),
            formName = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.formName);


        var progressMonitorID = controlId + '-ProgressMonitor';
        var progressIndicatorID = controlId + '-ProgressIndicator';

        var formID = controlId + '-form';
        var fileInputID = controlId + '-fileInput';

        if (uploadUrl) {
            $(element).change(function () {
                if (element.files.length) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        fileName = $this.val();

                    // var formData = new FormData($('#' + formName)[0]);

                    var $form = $('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id=' + formID + '></form>');
                    // $form.append('<input id=' + fileInputID + 'name=' + fileInputID + ' type="file" />');

                    $form.append('<input type="hidden" id="imageKey_"' + controlId + '  name="imageKey" value=' + imageKey + '>');
                    $form.append('<input type="hidden" id="imageForeignKey_"' + controlId + '  name="imageForeighKey01" value=' + imageForeighKey01 + '>');
                    $("#" + controlId).clone().appendTo($form);
                    $form.hide();
                    $('body').append($form);

                    var formData = new FormData($($form)[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: uploadUrl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false, //'multipart/form-data',
                        processData: false,
                        xhr: function () {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            //Upload progress
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100 + "%";
                                    //Do something with upload progress
                                    $('#' + progressMonitorID).show();
                                    $('#' + progressIndicatorID).width(percentComplete);
                                    //alert(percentComplete);
                                }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        }
                    })
                        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if (refreshUri) {
                                //alert("success"); 
                                //var path = '../MapView/DownloadMap?ref=' + Math.random();
                                var path = refreshUri + 'ref=' + Math.random();
                                options.refresh(path);
                            }
                        })
                        .fail(function (jqxhr, status, errorMsg) { alert("Status : " + status + " Error :" + errorMsg); })
                        .always(function () {
                            // alert("complete");
                            $('#' + progressMonitorID).hide();
                            $('#' + progressIndicatorID).hide();
                            $('#' + formID).remove();
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and html binding is

```
<input type="file" tabindex="9"
                                data-bind="attr: {
    id: 'RoadMap' + $index(), name: 'RoadMap' + $index()
},
    multiFileUpload: {
        controlId: 'RoadMap' + $index(),
        formName: 'frmPage3a',
        imageKey: StageDetailID,
        imageForeighKey01: CourseInfoRoadID,
        uploadUrl: '/api/Image/UploadMapFile'
    }
" />
```

this code works very fine into FireFox browser but not work in IE and Chrome.here the problem is .clone() method of jquery.
Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why it works on FF because no element exists with id "controlId". it's either imageKey_"' + controlId + ' or imageForeignKey_"' + controlId + '

Comment: Thanks your comment. I have mentioned my full code.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning id with an underscore and this is why not working. Use two backslashes to escape meta character. Like `$("#your\\_id")`

[see more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650)