# Replace colon in href attribute in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a problem handling IDs with a colon in jquery. If there is a colon in an ID the smooth scroll doesn't work.

**The HTML**

```
<a href="#fn:1">Go to Footnote 1</a>

<div id="fn:1>Lorem ipsum Bla Bla</div>
```

**JS**

```
  var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 400, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('[href]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace(/:/g,""));
    });
});
```

That will remove `:` from all `href`

Comment: Thank you Amit. I also removed ':' from 'id' so the links work.

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href'),
        href = href.split(':'),
        href = href.join('\\:');
      alert(href)
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 400, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69SeE/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `#` with `\\#` and `:` with `\\:` to escape the character and to make it work:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a').click(function() {
      var href = $.attr(this, 'href').replace(/:/g,"\\\\:");
      href = href.replace(/#/,"\\\\#");
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 400, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

See more about escaping the character [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650)