# Get ID of selected radio button in Jquery "name has []"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, brackets

I am using an online product and for some reason when it generated the page in question the name of the radio button set is product_id_page-0[] <-- "Note the []"

What I want to do is get the ID of the selected radio button using Jquery. If I use

```
    var userType =$('#product_id_page-0[]:radio:checked').attr('id');
    alert("xmlvalue is: " + userType);
```

Nothing happens

If I use

```
    var userType =$('#product_id_page-0:radio:checked').attr('id');
    alert("xmlvalue is: " + userType);
```

I get an alert with Undefined.

I can not change the radio button name group, but I am thinking that the brackets might be breaking something here.

Please advice.

Comment: According to your example, you are working with element ID and not with a name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape the meta character with the two slashes:

```
var userType =$('#product_id_page-0\\[\\]:radio:checked').attr('id');
    alert("xmlvalue is: " + userType);
```

if this is the name instead of id use:

```
var userType =$('[name=product_id_page-0\\[\\]]:radio:checked').attr('id');
        alert("xmlvalue is: " + userType);
```

[see more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650)