# can't hide the input field with ":" using css

Tags: html, css

Here is the html code

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="billing:region_id" class="">
        <em style="display: none;">*</em>city
    </label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="縣市" class="" style="display: none;" defaultvalue="">
            <option value="">please select</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "");
            //]]>
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="" title="region" class="input-text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the

```
<input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="" title="region" class="input-text">
```

with the css

```
#billing:region 
{
    display: none;
}
```

but it does not work. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use slash for meta character:

```
#billing\:region {
    display: none;
}
```

[see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650)

---

```
Comment response:
```

Like this?

```
[for="billing\:region"]{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @hkinterview Since `for` is an attribute, you can use [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select based on element attributes. The `\:` escaping would still apply for attribute selectors, since the `\ ` escaping metacharacter is a universal selector rule.