# How to access elements that were created in jQuery with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating elements using jQuery and assigning them IDs in the process. Later in my code, I want to access these elements via their ID. However, I am unable to do this with jQuery. If I use just core JS, it works, though. Why might this be?

```
var createTable = function(rows, columns, height, width) {
    var $table = $("<table>");
    $("body").append($table);

    for (var i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++) {
        var $tr = $("<tr>");
        $table.append($tr);
        for (var j = 1; j < columns + 1; j++) {
            var $td = $("<td>", { id: i + "." + j });
            $td.css("height", height + "px").css("width", width + "px")
               .css("border", "1px black solid");
            $tr.append($td);
        }
    }
}


createTable(4, 4, 150, 100);
```

Does not work:

```
$("#1.1").css("border", "1px red solid");
```

Works:

```
var onePointOne = document.getElementById("1.1");
onePointOne.style.border = "1px red solid";
```

Comment: See your code is working fine only [http://jsfiddle.net/wUf93/](http://jsfiddle.net/wUf93/)

Answer (score 3):

The dot has special meaning in selectors: they are class selectors. You will need to escape the dot to find the correct id:

```
$('#1\\.1')...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.` operator denotes to the class so it would search for id 1 and it's class 1 but you are not accessing to those but your id contains `.` a meta-character for which you need to use slash for escaping the meta character:

```
$("#1\\.1").css("border", "1px red solid");
```

[see more information about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650)

But I would recommend to you not to use `.` operator for your id, you could assign it like `1-1` for which you can easily access like `$('#1-1')`

And still more I would recommend you not to use id starting from number.

Comment: or, more simply and less "ugly", don't use a `.` in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it will work:

```
$("#1\\.1").css("border", "1px red solid !important");
```

Comment: no need to use important just escaping the character would work, and FYI, important like you are applying would not work....