# Jquery - cannot fetch attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple line of code:

```
var page=jQuery("#buy-items-button").attr('id');
```

Problem is that `page` is `undefined`. Relevant portion of html

```
<li><a id='#buy-items-button' href="#buy-items" data-page="buy-items" class="section-button">Buy Items</a></li>
```

`console.log(jQuery("#buy-items-button"))` shows:

```
[context: document, selector: "#buy-items-button", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
context: document
selector: "#buy-items-button"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Driving me crazy as having been using jQuery for long and never faced issues on such trivial calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `#` from id value of your anchor:

```
<li><a id='buy-items-button' href="#buy-items" data-page="buy-items" class="section-button">Buy Items</a></li>
```

Comment: Argh. Wasted 45 minutes before this. Going through all sorts of Jquery revision updates, scoping, etc. Sometimes human stupidity is infinite.

Comment: I've been burned so many times by this, and I never seem to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is wrong (remove # from id attribute):

```
<a id='#buy-items-button' href="#buy-items"
```

should be

```
<a id='buy-items-button' href="#buy-items"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
jQuery('a[id^="#buy-items"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute in your HTML is wrong. Remove the pound sign.

Comment: that is not wrong you can escape your special characters, or you can use attribute selectors with string values surrounded by quotes.