# Page scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I need to scroll on specific area. As there is tab I used this code but unable to achieve. 
I have tried this code for scrolling page on the Div area:

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click');">0 reviews</a>
```

Comment: Any reason to not set `href` attribute to: `#tab-review` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hash for [meta-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650):

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'\\#tab-review\']').trigger('click');">0 reviews</a>
```

Or, remove the hash in your link and use like this:

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'tab-review\']').trigger('click');">0 reviews</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#" id="reviewAnchor">0 reviews</a>

$("#reviewAnchor").click(function() {
    $("a[href='#tab-review']").trigger('click');
});
```