# bind Photoswipe close button with click event failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Photoswipe close button did not fire with click event?

This worked on general case. I've tried event preventDefault, event delegate, use inline style like onclick=function(), still doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pswp__button pswp__button--close' , function(){
  alert('d'); // did not fire?
});
```

full code look here http://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/zxNEjV

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector is wrong. replace `'.pswp__button pswp__button--close'` with `'.pswp__button.pswp__button--close'`

try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.pswp__button.pswp__button--close' , function(){
    alert('d');
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPdaLM)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to event from Photoswipe (PSWP)

```
document.querySelector('.pswp').addEventListener('pswpTap', function (e)
{
    // event 'pswpTap' handle all click events on whole Photoswipe container
    console.log(e)
    /* 
    //You can prevent any event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    */
}, true);
```