# JQuery - Change event using element by name

Tags: jquery

First of all I want to apologize for asking silly questions. I haven't found a good resource where I can search such questions. Please help.
I am customizing a page where date is defined as below. I can't add id for other reasons so have to use element name to call the change event.

```
<td><input type="text" class="psDateWidget"  name="[04]datestart" value="" size="10"></td>
```

When I use the name like this

```
 $j("input[name='[04]datestart]'").change(function()
```

It does not fire the event. Why? How can I make it work? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448626/how-to-take-id-as-selector-when-used-hash/22448650#22448650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to

```
$("input[name='[04]datestart']").change(function()
```

Remove the extra j adjacent to $.

You also have the closing square bracket inside the name selector `datestart]'"` and should be `datestart']"` instead.

Here is a working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/mKPDwgCLTwdxD6lFaX4j?p=preview

Comment: $("input[name='[04]datestart']").change(function().

It was like this -> ]'"
It must be like this ->']"

Comment: @RicardEspinàsLlovet I've amended the answer to include this detail too.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer is:

```
$("input[name='[04]datestart']").change(function(){


});
```

Comment: This answer is a simply a copy of the already accepted answer and doesn't add any further detail!